# Using XSLT to append multiple XML file to a single .csv file

Tags: xml, xslt

Let say my program are processing some data and output is a XML file. Anyway that I can possible to append out data based on my XSLT format into a single csv without overwriting the previous data?

Currently I have the below scenario

```
Trial 1:
Output = a.xml & after XSLT, output = a.csv with data 1,2,3,4,5
Trial 2: 
Output = b.xml & after XSLT, output = b.csv with data 6,7,8,9,0
```

Actually what I want is:-

```
Trial 1:
Output = a.xml & after XSLT, output = a.csv with data 1,2,3,4,5
Trial 2: 
Output = b.xml & after XSLT, output = b.csv with data(below)
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,0
```

Comment: XSLT does how have a concept of appending to files as far as I know.  How are you executing the XSLT?  You could probably just use code to append the XSLT result to the file you want to modify.

Comment: Most likely you would need to create two intermediate files in xml before processing them both in a final xslt stage into your final csv format.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your xml looks like.  Try using output method="text" and use strip-space for all elements.

Then for each element or attribute you wish to comma separate, use the xsl text.

The text for a comma is this:

```
<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
```